# unable to install sphinx in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-sphinx

I have a python 3.4 virtualenv and trying to install sphinx in it rises an error:

```
$ pip install sphinx
Collecting sphinx
  Using cached Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 (from sphinx)
  Using cached alabaster-0.7.4.tar.gz
  setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
```

I'm currently using my distribution's sphinx but It makes me pollute my `conf.py` and can't really find packages in autodoc.

Is it a known issue? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but when I faced the same problem, it was a lot faster to reinstall the virtual environment than trying to solve the issue (I tried updating pip, setuptools, etc). After setting up a new virtualenv, I had no problem installing or updating packages again.